# A question on the convergence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm interested in showing that the integral
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{1}^{t} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}\:d\theta$$
converges. I am aware that one can show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ using contour integration. But I was wondering if one can prove convergence without necessarily making use of this fact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done, and is done in many places, using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Feynman's technique;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(x)\over x}dx\space \rightarrow \space I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(x)\over x}\cdot e^{-ax}dx$$

$$\therefore {d\over da}I(a)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(x)}\cdot e^{-ax}dx$$

$$=-Im\bigg\{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(a-i)x} dx\bigg\}=Im\bigg\{{e^{-(a-i)x }\over(a-i)}{\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}} \bigg\}$$
$$=Im\bigg\{ {-1\over(a-i)}\bigg\}=Im\bigg\{ {-(a+i)\over(a^2+1)}\bigg\}={-1\over(a^2+1)}$$

$$\therefore I(a)=\int{-1\over(1+a^2)}da=-\arctan(a)+C$$

So we have;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(x)\over x}\cdot e^{-ax}dx=-\arctan(a)+C$$

Letting $a\rightarrow \infty$ reveals;

$$0=-{\pi\over2}+C \implies C={\pi\over2}$$

Which gives us our final result;

$$I(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(x)\over x}dx={\pi\over2}$$

Comment: FYI - this technique is much, much older than Feynman. Apparently Feynman had learned it and used it in some lectures attended by many who never had before, and assumed it was something he had come up with.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Lol that's not surprising. I usually refer to it by Feynman's name because that was how the idea was introduced to me during my physics education.

Comment: I'm not blaming you. I just like to set the record straight when I come across it. Feynman was enough of a genius, he doesn't need others work to be attributed to him as well.